Preventing viewing lag in ffplay when window is backgrounded on Ubuntu
I'm using ffplay to stream live video on Ubuntu 22.04 LTS on a laptop that only uses the CPU (no GPU). Here’s the command I’m running:
$ ffplay -f live_flv -fast -fflags nobuffer -flags low_delay \
    -strict experimental -vf "setpts=N/30/TB" -an -noframedrop \
    -i rtmp://localhost:1935/live

I’ve noticed that when the ffplay window is sent to the background, a noticeable lag develops in the stream, and this delay persists even after I bring the window back to the foreground. However, if I leave the window in the foreground from the start, the stream runs smoothly without any latency.
I suspect Ubuntu might be lowering the process priority when the window is in the background. Anyway, is there a way to prevent this delay, ensuring the stream runs smoothly whether the window is in the background or foreground?

@Destroy666: Thanks a lot. I am setting it to -10 for now and seems working.

To change priority of any starting process in Linux, including for purpose like trying to make ffplay stream less laggy, you can change its niceness with nice command:
nice -n -20 command

where -20 is the highest priority and 19 the lowest and command i just the full command you'd like to use.
